# How to mock os.walk in python with a temporary filesystem?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm trying to test some code that uses os.walk. I want to create a temporary, in-memory filesystem that I can populate with sample (empty) files and directories that os.walk will then return. This should save me the complexity of mocking os.walk calls to simulate recursion.

Specifically, the code I want to test is:

```
if recursive:
    log.debug("Recursively searching for files under %s" % path)

    for (dir_path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
        log.debug("Found %d files in %s: %s" % (len(files), path, files))
        for f in [os.path.join(dir_path, f) for f in files
                  if not re.search(exclude, f)]:
            yield f
else:
    log.debug("Non-recursively searching for files under %s" % path)

    for (dir_path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
        log.debug("Found %d files in %s: %s" % (len(files), path, files))
        for f in [os.path.join(dir_path, f) for f in files
                    if not re.search(exclude, f)]:
            yield f
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: Do you want to mock only the lists returned, or full file-like functionality?

Comment: Only the lists returned.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No. `os.walk()` is constructed entirely around [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir), with assistance of `os.path.islink()` and `os.path.isdir()`. These are essentially system calls, so you'd have to mock your filesystem *at the system level*. Unless you want to write a [FUSE plugin](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) this is not going to be easy to mock.

All `os.walk()` needs to return is a list of tuples, really. Unless you are testing manipulating the `dirs` component, it couldn't be more simple:

```
with mock.patch('os.walk') as mockwalk:
    mockwalk.return_value = [
        ('/foo', ('bar',), ('baz',)),
        ('/foo/bar', (), ('spam', 'eggs')),
    ]
```

This would mock the following directory structure:

```
/foo
 ├── baz
 └── bar 
     ├── spam
     └── eggs
```

Comment: I thought it'd be more difficult. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I wrote my solution a little more condensed but this helped me with my solution as well. Remember "os.walk() needs to return a **list of tuples**". My solution:  
`@patch('test_module.os.walk')  
def test_walk(self, os_walk):  
  os.walk.return_value[('/foo', ('',), ('file.txt',))]
`

Comment: I think a `=` is missing there; `os.walk.return_value` is not indexable. :-)

Comment: actually `(), ('spam', 'eggs')` could be `[], ['spam', 'eggs']`. not that yours won't work here but it wouldn't hurt to resemble the real one more closely either.

Comment: @naxa: it would, actually, because if you change your code-under-test to manipulate the `dir` component especially, the test would need updating. You'd easily forget about that if you were to use lists. :-)